# Can't delete a row from SQLITE database

Tags: javascript, web-applications, sqlite

I have a weird problem with my sqlite-datase. I can insert and display my data but I can't delete them (especially when I do a "equal to" query).

Here's my code:

```
<body>

<div id="results">
    Results:
</div>

<button onclick="insert_id(); return false;">Insert</button>
<button onclick="show_id(); return false;">Show</button>
<button onclick="delete_id(); return false;">Delete</button>

<script>
var db = openDatabase("testdb", "1.0", "testdb favourites", 2*1024*1024);

function insert_id(){
    db.transaction(
    function(t){ // This is the callback with "t" as the transaction object
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favourites (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY)");
    }
);

var rec_id = "40";

db.transaction(
    function(t){
    t.executeSql("INSERT INTO favourites VALUES (?)", [rec_id]);
    }
);
}

function show_id(){
var list = document.getElementById("results");
var rec_id = 0;

db.transaction(
 function(t){
  t.executeSql("SELECT id AS rec_id FROM favourites WHERE id > ?" ,[rec_id], function(t,r){
     for (var i=0; i < r.rows.length; i++){
      rec_id = r.rows.item(i).rec_id;           

      list.innerHTML +="<li>"+rec_id+"</li>";           
        }
    }, 

    function(t,e){alert("Fehler: " + e.message + "\n\nBitte melde dich bei bauchalarm@outlook.com wenn der Fehler öfters auftritt!");})
}
);
}

function delete_id(){
var rec_id = 40;

db.transaction(
 function(t){
  t.executeSql("DELETE FROM favourites WHERE id = ?", [rec_id]);
        }
);
}
</script>

</body>
```

If I query `WHERE id < 40` all data below 40 (AND the id with 40) will be deleted... but when I query `WHERE id = 40` nothing happens...

Comment: Doesn't the `id` column need to be referenced as `_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your ID being TEXT instead of a INT.

Try changing the create table to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favourites (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
```